# How can I make a column that stores the time that row was created in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

After tons of googling I could not find an answer. I want to create a column in mysql that stores the the time that row was created as HH:MM:SS

I'm making a chat room and the table currently has a column for the message and id

I dont want do use timestamp or datetime as I don't want to have date month year etc. just Hour min and sec.

I tried time but it always say the time is 00:00:00

**EDIT:** I guess I want to be able to echo only time from time stamp.

I tried `echo '<div><p>User@' . substr($value['Time'], 11) . '->' . $value['message'] . '</p></div>';` But it does not work.

Comment: why not use `datetime` or `timestamp`, you can still extract time on those. anyway maybe you're looking for `time` datatype

Comment: ^^^ Beat me to it, saved me from typing.

Comment: *"I tried time but it always say the time is 00:00:00"* - Code would be nice. *Oh,* and the answer was already inside phpMyAdmin ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah most likely its just a problem on insertion, there is no problem with having to insert a datetime. you can still extract the time in there

Comment: @Ghost I tried time datatype but its always 00:00:00

Comment: tried what? exact code please

Comment: @Dagon I added a column through the structure tab with name 'Time' dataype 'TIME' and thats it because neither'NOW()' nor 'CURTIME()' worked for default

Comment: @Sawyer If you're actually including quotes in `'NOW()'` in your query, then yeah, it won't work. Do show us your code. We can't guess till midnight. `INSERT INTO table (column_x, column_y) VALUES ('text', NOW())` <= proven method. `('text', 'NOW()')` <= invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edited Answer

If you want to use a regular `TIMESTAMP` field in MySQL, first create the field.

```
ALTER TABLE  `YourTable` ADD  `LastAccessed` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

Once you have setup the field you can leave it alone.  When you insert a record pass `null` as the value and it will default to the current time.  When you update the record the time will be adjusted.

To obtain the time from the `TIMESTAMP` field you will need to run your select query and get your results.  For illustrative purposes, this would look something like the following:

```
//Integrate this into your existing code
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT LastAccessed FROM YourTable"); //get only the time field for this example
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$time = new DateTime($row['LastAccessed']); //The constructor accepts the time information as an argument
echo $time->format("H:i:s"); //This is your time information.
```

Since you have a `TIMESTAMP` field now, not only will the database take responsibility for updating it with the correct time, but you can always modify the `$time->format()` method's argument to produce a string with time data in a variety of different ways.

The timestamp gets abstracted and your application gain flexibility.

Win-Win, right?

#### Original Answer

Create a `char(8)` column in MySQL and then send it the output from a call to:

`date("H:i:s");`

Although using a timestamp field in MySQL would be optimal, considering you can have it update when the record is interacted with.  You don't *have* to use the entire timestamp.

- [Date function in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [Working with timestamps in MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx)

Comment: suggesting bad ideas, is a bad idea

Comment: @Dagon Hmmm.... I was answering the question based on OP's desired results _while also_ suggesting a better idea.  Might not have been the best idea, but it is what was asked.

Comment: OP didn't want to share query code which is the main reason why I didn't bother putting in an answer, which I **never** do for questions like these; they're just a great big can of worms. OP is obviously doing something wrong. From what I gather from comments, OP is using quotes around functions; that's what I got out of it. After being asked a few times to share code, OP still hasn't posted it. I voted to close.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, reviewing the couple comments that came in after my answer it seems that OP was going about it wrong from the beginning.  Initially what I took from it is that OP wanted a field that would store _only_ the time, which you aren't getting with a regular timestamp.  Hopefully he follows the link to the timestamp tutorial and works with that instead.

Comment: Hopefully, but OP seems to have *left the building*. I'd wait on **:::ELVIS:::**, but not on this guy ;)

Comment: Seems OP accepted the answer, finally. Plus, you going the "extra mile" certainly deserves a +1. Whoever DV, should take it back. *Cheers*