# A field that stores the time the row was inserted and doesn't change it on update

Tags: mysql, timestamp

According to what I've read in some posts such as the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417130/how-can-i-make-a-column-that-stores-the-time-that-row-was-created-in-mysql)

passing null value in a `timestamp` field will store the date when the row was created, but will update it when row is edited.

I want to do the same thing but without changing the date, and having that time stored as UTC, how can I do that?

Comment: See the manual.

Comment: @tadman can you post it as an answer please? so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to create a trigger to apply the change, or do it in your application code.

As a note, `TIMESTAMP` fields are really awful and shouldn't be used as they are subject to the [2038 overflow issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) while `DATETIME` is not. A `DATETIME` can go thousands of years into the past and into the future, which is hopefully enough.